# Database Table for customer user

Tags: database, login, front-end

I'm developing a custom login system for wordpress. In front-end, the customers, has the possibility to register, etc...But I'm wondering if is possible to store customer information in other table than wp_user. Is possible? And what are pros and cons.

Any suggestion is appreciate.

Comment: You can store data in any table which you created or other. but you need to execute a custom query to do that. the better way to do this extend existing wp form and save data. you can use WP action for this. if your not familiar with custom query use a wp plugin.

Comment: Of course it is possible. Pros and cons depend on what you are doing with these data. Since you left out that information it's impossible to answer that. :)

Comment: Hi there. Tanks for your reply. My idea is to understand what conflict can be generated by saving customer in other table with other plugin like woocommerce, for exemple. Other that I want that if a customer add credential in wp_login have an error message for bad credential displayed, instead in front-end can access without problem. Thanks again

Comment: No other hints?